# Eclipse CDT and PGI (Portland) C++ compiler

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-construction

Can someone please tell me how to setup Eclipse CDT to build using the PGI C++ compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this documentation with a simple web search:

[www.pgroup.com/doc/pgiug.pdf](http://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgiug.pdf)

Go through the chapter 8. Tell me if it helps.

Comment: I searched the forum at pgroup.com. Turns I should have just looked at the manual :)